# Can vou add some more detail?

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

[image: Can vou add some more detail]

Comment: I'm sure they'll need to know browser for this one.

Comment: Firefox 4 and Chrome 12 both have this bug

Comment: What am I missing here?

Comment: @Sathya: **vou** instead of **you** (not a typo, just a rendering issue)

Comment: Should be «vous», then, right? This is français.stackexchange.com, right?

Comment: @Josh: actually with the CSS bug it would be "francais.stackexchanɑe.com".

Comment: @NickDandoulakis - thanks, I missed that.

Comment: Just use IE. Those other browsers are just a passing fad and will never catch on.

Answer (score 3):

The combination of line-height and image overlap was the issue here, but fixing that affects a bit more than we'd like.  However, `2px` padding can work wonders...so this will appear correctly after the next build.

Answer (score 2):

I see the problem in Chrome, but there's more of a tail in Firefox.

Firefox 4.0:

[image: Firefox VOU]

Chrome 12:

[image: Chrome VOU]